pick random name from a column when triggered, and write name and timestamp to a log
I want to allow a user to copy a list of names into a column in a google sheet, then click a checkbox or button to generate a randomly picked name.  I want that name to be logged by adding it to a row of the same (or a separate) sheet along with the timestamp (in the next cell in that same row).  Then I want to clear the picked name and allow the user to pick another name which would be added to the log on the next blank row.
My current sheet is at https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EAMXXkG8nNS6lgdAZIZ6qKYo_yxsVJRllMj1B26UMdM/edit?usp=sharing

Welcome to Web Applications Stack Exchange.

The question is an exact copy of pick random name from a column when manually triggered, and write name and timestamp to a log. See Be Forthright When Cross Posting To Other Sites.

I suspect that is only doable with a script. Here's some code to get you started:
'use strict';

/**
* Simple trigger that runs each time the user manually edits the spreadsheet.
*
* @param {Object} e The onEdit() event object.
*/
function onEdit(e) {
  if (!e) throw new Error('Please do not run the onEdit(e) function in the script editor window. It runs automatically when you hand edit the spreadsheet. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63851123/13045193.');
  addRandomName_(e);
}


/**
* Pick a random name and and append it with a timestamp in Sheet1!B2:C.
*
* @param {Object} e The onEdit() event object.
*/
function addRandomName_(e) {
  if (e.value !== 'TRUE' || e.range.getA1Notation() !== 'D8') return;
  const names = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('Sheet1!A2:A')
    .getDisplayValues()
    .flat()
    .filter(String);
  const randomName = names[Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length)];
  appendRows_(e.range.getSheet(), [randomName, new Date()], 'B:C');
  e.range.uncheck();
}

For that to work, you will need to paste the appendRows_() and getLastRow_() utility functions in your script project as well. You can get those functions from How to append data to a certain column?
